# Append 'Continue Reading' link if post length is more than 3 lines of text?

Tags: posts, blog

I'm pretty new to coding for Wordpress, bear with me.

I have a section on my home page, that lists the 2 most recent blog posts.

If the text goes past three lines, my design gets messed up. So I was wondering if there was a native function that exists for me to append 'Continue Reading' automagically and allow the user to click that link to bring them to the full blog post?

For example, this is what I do NOT want:

[image: Bad]

This, is what I do want, I did the design in Photoshop and this is what I'd like to happen if the posts are going to be longer than 3 lines of text.

[image: Good]

Thanks, I'll try to clarify anything if need be!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the lines, I would try to go for characters or words. The example below uses characters.

Don't take my word on it as it hasn't been tested.

```
$character == 40; // number of characters to compare
if(mb_strlen( get_the_content() < $character){
the_content();
}else{
the_content('Continue Reading...')
}
```

Alternatively by word count.

```
$words == 20; // number of characters to compare
if(str_word_count(get_the_content(),0)  < $words){
the_content();
}else{
the_content('Continue Reading...')
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, I will attempt this, and let you know if I have any questions! If not I'll mark as answer and post my solution.

Comment: I've tried this, using the following code: <div class="post_text"> <?php $words == 20; // number of characters to compare  if(str_word_count(get_the_content(),0) < $words){ //if str_word count is less than words the_content();} //display the content normally else{the_content('Continue Reading...');} //otherwise, change it to continue reading ?> Which, didn't work. I had to change a line or two to make the theme not fail, but no matter what value I assigned to $words nothing happened. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that *lines* is not a unit that PHP can understand, because is a unit related more to the display than to the content, in short it cannot be *measured* by PHP.

In Wordpress what you want is done with the function [`the_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) that I bet is used in your theme. *(Be sure to read the link provided, is full of useful informations for you)*

As said, lines is not a valid unit for PHP, in fact, `the_excerpt` use the number of words as limit. By default it's limited to 55 words.

How to change: first method is use a filter, like so:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function() { return 20; }, 99 );
```

In this way the 'summary' of your post that is visible will counts 20 words.

When the excerpt is created, cutting a certain number of words from the post content, `[...]` is appended to the excerpt.

To avoid this, you can use another filter:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', function() { return ''; }, 99 );
```

In this way nothing is appended to the *trimmed* text. If you want append something, just put what you want inside `''` in previous function.

Another way to decide where the 'summary' should end, is to *manual* insert the excerpt in the posts when you create them:

[image: manual excerpt]

In this way you can exactly decide where the summary should end.

For what regarding the length of the excerpt, I think that now you can control it, now we can answer the second part of your question.

The more easy way to add a 'Continue Reading' is just add the link to post using `get_permalink();` so, where in your code you have `the_excerpt()`, replace with:

```
the_excerpt(); printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink(), 'Continue Reading...');
```

Note that this will *always* add the link to single post, even if the post is shorter than the excerpt lenght.

To add the link only if the post content is longer than excerpt, you can leave the template using only `the_excerpt();` and use the previous explained 'excerpt_more' filter, where instead of returning an empty string you return the link to post:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', function() {
  return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Continue Reading...</a>';
});
```

### Please Note:

In this answer I assumed that your template use `the_excerpt` to show the post summary, that is the most common way, but some themes handle this in differet ways, so if the code posted doesn't work for you, your theme are probably using a different way... In that case, update your question adding the code of your template, and for sure, someone will help you soon.

Comment: Very thorough, I tried Andre's solution and was unsuccessful. I am reading through your information and links, I've never heard of `the_exerpt` until now! I will let you know how I fare, and post a solution and mark yours as answer if it helps me out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to truncate text according to characters or words, even sentences, but there is no way for PHP to know how many lines of text you have. That calculation is made by the browser after the content has left the server and depends on screen size, window width, fonts, the browser itself, even some browser plugins can alter things. Additionally, the length of the words can change the "flow" and the "wrap" of the text-- drives our designers crazy since they are used to designing for print where all of those things can be rigidly controlled.

To get close to what you want, you need Javascript but that is off-topic here. With PHP, the best you get is something like @AndreYonadam posted (which I upvoted) or @G-M's (which I also upvoted), but there are numerous other questions here with similar answers.